# OpenIddict - Introspect doesn’t work in Docker

Tags: docker, openiddict

Introspect doesn’t work in Docker, micro-services developed in .net core 2.0 web api, setup using openiddict and the code using Implicit flow. Container port 80 is mapped with host machine post 32774, where identity micro-service is running, and on 32775 port, when Other service Authorize method is called from postman result in following error.

```
        <h1>An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.</h1>
    <div class="titleerror">CurlException: Couldn&#x27;t connect to server</div>
    <p class="location">System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)</p>
    <div class="titleerror">HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.</div>
    <p class="location">System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()</p>
    <div class="titleerror">IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: &#x27;http://localhost:32774/.well-known/openid-configuration&#x27;.</div>
    <p class="location">Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever&#x2B;&lt;GetDocumentAsync&gt;d__8.MoveNext()</p>
    <div class="titleerror">InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: &#x27;http://localhost:32774/.well-known/openid-configuration&#x27;.</div>
    <p class="location">Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager&#x2B;&lt;GetConfigurationAsync&gt;d__24.MoveNext()</p>
```

And following error in System log

```
The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
and APPID 
{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
to the user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM SID (S-1-5-18) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not caused by OpenIddict. You likely have a routing or firewall issue that prevents communication between your containers.

Comment: @Pinpoint, Thanks for your reply, I turned off windows firewall and changed OpenIddictApplications.RedirectUris to match Identity URL, still no luck.